# jsf 2.2 passThroughAttribute works for table but not working for th

Tags: jsf-2.2

I'm trying to add data-priority attribute to the dataTable's column header, <th>, using myfaces jsf2.2.8 passThroughAttribute.  But it does not seems to be working.  Strange part is that it works for <table>.

Below is the jsf code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    class="ui-mobile">

<h:head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}#{resource['default:css/itMobile.css']}&amp;v=#{myacctResources['it.css.version']}" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/default/1_0/css/jqueryMobile1.4.5-myam-theme/jquery.mobile.myam.theme.min.css?v=#{myacctResources['it.js.version']}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/default/1_0/css/jqueryMobile1.4.5-myam-theme/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css?v=#{myacctResources['it.js.version']}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/default/1_0/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css?v=#{myacctResources['it.js.version']}" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}#{resource['default:js/jquery.js']}&amp;v=#{myacctResources['it.js.version']}"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/default/1_0/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js?v=#{myacctResources['it.js.version']}"></script>   

    <script>
      //<![CDATA[
      $(document).ready(function(){
      });
      //]]>
    </script>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:dataTable a:data-role="table" a:data-mode="columntoggle" a:data-column-btn-text="col" styleClass="ui-responsive myList" id="myList" value="#{testBean.myListModel}" var="item">

        <h:column rowHeader="true">
            <f:passThroughAttribute name="data-priority" value="1"/>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Seq
            </f:facet>                      
            <h:outputText value="#{item.seq}" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:passThroughAttribute name="data-priority" value="2"/>
            <f:facet name="header">
                Value
            </f:facet>                      
            <h:outputText value="#{item.value}" />
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>  
</h:body>
</html>
```

Below is the result I'm getting

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ui-mobile">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/javax.faces.resource/css/itMobile.css.jsf?ln=default&amp;v=05152015g" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/default/1_0/css/jqueryMobile1.4.5-myam-theme/jquery.mobile.myam.theme.min.css?v=05152015g" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/default/1_0/css/jqueryMobile1.4.5-myam-theme/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css?v=05152015g" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/default/1_0/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css?v=05152015g" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/js/jquery.js.jsf?ln=default&amp;v=05152015g"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/default/1_0/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js?v=05152015g"></script> 

    <script>
      //<![CDATA[
      $(document).ready(function(){
      });
      //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="myList" class="ui-responsive myList" data-column-btn-text="col" data-mode="columntoggle" data-role="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Seq</th>
                <th scope="col">Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="myList:tbody_element"> 
            <tr> 
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>itsy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>bitsy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>spider</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the result, the table passThroughAttribute works fine:
a:data-role="table" and <f:passThroughAttribute name="data-model" value="columntoggle"/> are showing in table element

But the th passThroughAttribute are not.

When I try the same jsf page using mojarra 2.2.11, I get other problems.  The passThroughAttribute specified for h:column is being added to <th>.  But it is also being added to <td>.  I only want it to be on <th>  The passThroughAttribute specified on dataTable, is being added to <table>, <thead>, <tbody>, and <tr>.  I only want it to be on <table> only.

Below is the result page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ui-mobile">
<head id="j_idt2">
    <meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/javax.faces.resource/css/itMobile.css.jsf?ln=default&amp;v=1_0&amp;v=05152015g" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/default/1_0/css/jqueryMobile1.4.5-myam-theme/jquery.mobile.myam.theme.min.css?v=05152015g" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/default/1_0/css/jqueryMobile1.4.5-myam-theme/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css?v=05152015g" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/default/1_0/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css?v=05152015g" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javax.faces.resource/js/jquery.js.jsf?ln=default&amp;v=1_0&amp;v=05152015g"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/default/1_0/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js?v=05152015g"></script> 

    <script>
      //<![CDATA[
      $(document).ready(function(){
      });
      //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="myList" class="ui-responsive myList" data-role="table" data-column-btn-text="col" data-mode="columntoggle">
        <thead data-role="table" data-column-btn-text="col" data-mode="columntoggle">
            <tr data-role="table" data-column-btn-text="col" data-mode="columntoggle">
                <th scope="col" data-priority="1">
                    Seq
                </th>
                <th scope="col" data-priority="2">
                    Value
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-role="table" data-column-btn-text="col" data-mode="columntoggle">
            <tr data-role="table" data-column-btn-text="col" data-mode="columntoggle">
                <th scope="row" data-priority="1">1</th>
                    <td data-priority="2">itsy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-role="table" data-column-btn-text="col" data-mode="columntoggle">
                <th scope="row" data-priority="1">2</th>
                <td data-priority="2">bitsy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-role="table" data-column-btn-text="col" data-mode="columntoggle">
                <th scope="row" data-priority="1">3</th>
                <td data-priority="2">spider</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working now, because you're applying the `<f:passThroughAttribute/>` on the wrong item. At the end of the day, it's still the `h:column` that's rendered as the `th`, which is why you should be applying the passthrough on that, not the `f:facet`. So what you should have instead is

```
  <h:column rowHeader="true">
        <f:passThroughAttribute name="data-priority" value="1"/>
        <f:facet name="header">
            Seq
        </f:facet>                      
        <h:outputText value="#{item.seq}" />
  </h:column>
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, but still not working.  I've updated the jsf page and the result to reflect the change I made for this.  Note: I'm using myface 2.2.8.

Comment: Sorry I can't confirm that then @HockChaiLim; I tested this on mojarra 2.2.1

Comment: I'm not using maven on my project.  If I want to try mojarra 2.2.11, do I only need to download javax.faces-2.2.11.jar file from this link https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.11/?  No other dependency are needed?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of @HockChaiLim. You must take care to clean out your app server's implementation of JSF and traces of MyFaces also - JavaEE classloading issues are a major irritation to clear

Comment: Yes, I use websphere 8.0, which comes with jsf2.0. It took me 3 days to figure out how to make it use myfaces 2.2. I just changed it to use mojarra 2.2. Now I have two new problems:  The passThroughAttribute on dataTable is being added to <table>, <thead>, <tbody>, <tr>, which caused jquerymobile columtoggle to be displayed on each row.  The passThroughAttribute on h:column is being added to <th> and <td>, this does not seems to be causing any problem in jquerymobile, but I would prefer to have it on <th> only.

Comment: Go down to 2.2.0 @HockChaiLim (my mistake, I was running my 2.2.0. sandbox)

Comment: gotten same result as 2.2.11 when using 2.2.0.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce that on my 2.2.0/Glassfish build @HockChaiLim .  But at least you can be sure this is certainly a JSF implementation/distribution-specific bug

Comment: Thanks kolossus.  The fact is that no matter how this problem is fixed, it will never satisfy all situations.  If it is fixed to only add the attribute to the table element, then it won't work if someone only want the attribute to be added in tr, tbody or thead.  I going to try solve my problem by  using ui:repeat to create a table.  Never done that before, but looks like I've no choice.